# How do I save data from xml file in related tables using ef core?

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am creating the associated table like in the photos below. How do I save data in my related tables via XML?[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried to do it but got the following error, I don't know how to do it either.

Comment: Your code makes error is caused because you do not convert to the correct type.But not sure if it could read the file correctly when all the property types match well because not sure the element you get is corrct or not.So please share your xml file.

Comment: Also,please share the code instead of pictures!

Answer (score 0):

For how to resolve your backend error:

```
public void SaveXMLFile(string path)
{
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(path);
    List<Product> products = xDocument.Descendants("product").Select(p => new Product()
    {
        Productld = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("ProductId").Value),
        AlisFiyati = long.Parse(p.Element("AlisFiyati").Value),
        Fiyat = long.Parse(p.Element("Fiyat").Value),
        KDVOrani = long.Parse(p.Element("KDVOrani").Value),
        IndirimliFiyatMi = bool.Parse(p.Element("IndirimliFiyatMi").Value),
        Indirim = long.Parse(p.Element("Indirim").Value),
        HavaleIndirimOrani = long.Parse(p.Element("HavaleIndirimOrani").Value),
        StokAdedi = long.Parse(p.Element("StokAdedi").Value),
        GarantiSuresi = long.Parse(p.Element("GarantiSuresi").Value),
        Resim1 = new Uri(p.Element("Resim1").Value),
        Resim2 = new Uri(p.Element("Resim2").Value),
        Resim3 = new Uri(p.Element("Resim3").Value),
        Resim4 = new Uri(p.Element("Resim4").Value),
        Resim5 = new Uri(p.Element("Resim5").Value),
        Resim6 = new Uri(p.Element("Resim6").Value),
        Puani = Convert.ToDouble(p.Element("Resim6").Value),
        ConnectProducts = new List<ConnectProduct>(){
            new ConnectProduct() {
                Features = new Features()
                {
                    Adet = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("Adet"))
                }
            }
        }
    }).ToList();
}
```